# Как сменить консоль на интерфейс ubuntu в виртуальной машине?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

Как сменить консоль на интерфейс ubuntu в виртуальной машине?

/etc/update-motd.d/ * - не помогает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Интерфейс ubuntu - это имеется ввиду кнопочный интерфейс? с окошками?

Comment: @KoVadim, да, раньше он был, но что то случилось и все пропало.. не знаю как запустить

Comment: слишком много неизвестного, но попробуйте просто запустить `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm start`, что бы стартануть окно логина.

Comment: @KoVadim пишет что команда не найдена

Comment: какая именно - sudo или lightdm?

Comment: @KoVadim второе -  lightdm

Comment: значит либо Вы в процессе снесли все, либо у вас используется другой менеджер. Давайте найдем его. `ls /etc/init.d/*dm` показывает что то?

Comment: @KoVadim ls: невозможно получить доступ к "ls /etc/init.d/*dm" нет такого файла или каталога

Comment: прикольно. Похоже на неудачные эксперименты с системой. Попробуйте с установки его `sudo apt-get install -y lightdm` и потом снова запускайте

Comment: при установке появляется большое количество таких ошибок: "не удалось получить временная ошибка при разрешении "

Comment: собвстенно, что и требовалось доказать... Обновите систему, разрешите конфликты и пробуйте снова. Или просто установите по новому.. Почитайте, например это https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-find-and-fix-broken-packages-on-linux/ и попробуйте восстановить. Это очень хорошее упражнение

Comment: @KoVadim как можно достать файлы из убунты? и можно ли в такой ситуации?

Comment: все нашел, спасибо большое